# Angular HttpClient - accessing value buried in response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bootstrap

I am accessing an online API and want to use the text value to populate a ngb-typeahead dropdown. There is a [working example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) on the Angular Bootstrap website using Wikipedia, but the returned data from the Wikipedia API is different to the data I am getting from a geocoding API. The data I get is returned in this format:

```
{
 "suggestions": [
  {
   "text": "23 Queen Charlotte Drive, Aotea, Porirua, Wellington, 5024, NZL",
   "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDMwNzcyNzQjbG5nPTMzI2huPTIzI2xicz0xMDk6NDg1NDQwMzU=",
   "isCollection": false
  },
  {
   "text": "23 Queen Mary Avenue, Epsom, Auckland, 1023, NZL",
   "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDMwNDY4MjUjbG5nPTMzI2ZhPTE0NDE3OTIjaG49MjMjbGJzPTEwOTo0ODU0NDMyNA==",
   "isCollection": false
  },
```

I have been trying to access `text` in response data with the following:

```
return this.http
  .get<any>(GIS_URL, {params: GIS_PARAMS.set('text', term)}).pipe(
    map(response => response.suggestions)
  );
```

I have also read the Angular tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) on dealing with response data, but the difference in the example is that they are getting an array of Hero's whereas I am getting an object containing an array of suggestions.

The typeahead looks like:

[image]

#### HTML

```
<fieldset class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="typeahead-http">Search for a wiki page:</label>
    <input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control mx-sm-3" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="Wikipedia search" />
    <small *ngIf="searching" class="form-text text-muted">searching...</small>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, suggestions could not be loaded.</div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<hr>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

Full code on StackBlitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5zmgq-8nsbqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-http.ts).

I am new to Angular, so a verbose answer would be great.

Comment: could you change "response.suggestions" to "console.log(response)"? then we can see what object is being returned

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida map(response => console.log(response)) doesn't compile with Expected 0 arguments, but got 2

Comment: That should have worked but try 'tap(console.log)' instead of the entire map line.

Comment: @wlf sorry have updated question. stackblitz might help. What is full line for tap(console.log) and where to put?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify `resultFormatter` and `inputFormatter` on the typeahead `input` (refer to *[Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api)*).

#### Explanation

Your `search` method in the service returns a list of suggestion Objects which each look like:

```
{
  isCollection: ...
  magicKey: ...
  text: ...
}
```

However by default the typeahead control expects a list of strings, hence it displays your objects as [Object object].

You need to tell the typeahead control how to determine a string value from your object, you do this via `resultFormatter` and `inputFormatter`.

These inputs take a function, which has the object as an input and the string display value as its output.

`formatter` below is that function, it will be called for each item displayed in the list. If you expand it to a normal function you can put a breakpoint in it and see it being called in this manner.

#### Solution

```
<input id="typeahead-http" ... [inputFormatter]="formatter" [resultFormatter]="formatter"/>
```

TypeScript file:

```
formatter = (item:any) => item.text as string;
```

#### Updated StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-typeahead?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-http.ts

#### Follow-up questions

1. `item` in the formatter:

   Consider:

   ```
    formatter = (item:any) => item.text as string;
   ```

   is shorthand for:

   ```
    function format(item: any){
      return item.text as string;
    }
   ```

   They typeahead control/directive iterates the items returned by `search(..)` and calls this method which each one. The results are displayed in the select list.
2. `map(response => response.suggestions)`

   The response from the service is an object like:

   ```
    {  // object
      suggestions:
        [
          { ..., text: 'Place 1' },
          { ..., text: 'Place 2' }
        ]
    }
   ```

   That is an object containing a list named `suggestions`. The typeahead expects a list only, so the `map` transforms the object containing list => list only.
3. Does the formatter that you have defined do both input and result?

   Yes, as it is assigned to both `[inputFormatter]` and `[resultFormatter]` in the template.

Comment: can you provide some explanation on what the formatter is doing? I see that "item" is never explicitly assigned a value etc.

Comment: @AlGrant added explanation, let me know if you need any further clarification

Comment: thats pretty good. Can you talk to "item" thats in the formatter a little bit? and i presume map(response => response.suggestions) - response.suggestions is the first step to access the list inside suggestions?

Comment: And does the formatter that you have defined do both input and result?

Comment: see above for further answers

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative answer**

The mapping is done entirely in the service:

```
return this.http
      .get<any>(GIS_URL, {params: GIS_PARAMS.set('text', term)}).pipe(
        map(response => response.suggestions.map(suggestion => suggestion.text)),
      );
```

Each response object is mapped to the list of suggestions. Each suggestion is mapped (using JavaScript map) to its text value.

You can use this solution provided you don't need access to any of the other suggestion properties outside of the service.